# Method with same type erasure work-around without renaming method name

Tags: java

Without renaming the method what's the best way to get around this type-erasure:

```java
GetResultSet<Entity> getEntities(String entityType, Map<String,PropertyCondition> propertyConditions);
GetResultSet<Entity> getEntities(String entityType, Map<String, BlobCondition> blobConditions);
```

Comment: Because erasure literally means the stuff between `<>` is erased, there is no difference between those method signatures and there's nothing that can be done besides renaming the methods.  As far as I know, anyway.

Comment: How about reversing the order of the parameters of one of them? Make one of them accept a more concrete type than `Map`? Change one of the `String` parameters to `char[]`? This is a rather broad question as it stands.

Comment: With nothing to distinguish these methods besides the generics, I think renaming both might be a good idea anyway.  `getEntitiesByProperty` and `getEntitiesWithBlob` might work out better in the long run.  Sometimes pithiness is not a virtue.

Comment: Passing in a `String entityType` instead of having that type-checked against a generic return type `GetResultSet<T>` has a bit of a design-smell, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the first comment it is not possible because after type erasure the method signatures would be the same.

To preserve as much type safety and to have "only one method name" I would make just one method:

```
<T extends Condition> GetResultSet<Entity> getEntities(String entityType, 
                                               Map<String, T> propertyConditions);
```

and let both `PropertyCondition` and `BlobCondition` to implement this new `interface Condition` (or maybe abstract class).

Good thing would be that you can move possible common methods as interface default (or abstract class) methods. Bad thing would be that you would then have to use `instanceof` operator to make any implementation specific handling.

Comment: Yeah, this actually makes sense

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to rename the method.

You could also replace the maps with dedicated subclasses to describe the filter options (because their types won't get erased):

```
class PropertyConditions { Map<String, PropertyCondition> conditions }

GetResultSet<Entity> getEntities(String entityType, PropertyConditions propertyConditions);
```

If you want confusing workarounds, you could also disambiguate the parameter signatures by switching the order of parameters, or introducing dummy parameters.

Comment: Yeah this is what I ended up eventually

Answer (score 0):

You could keep one of the methods and inside that `getEntities` check the `instanceOf` of the member of the Map and act accordingly.

Adding dummy-parameter does solve the issue, but that way you'll have to go through all the cases these methods were called and add the parameter.